# python ttk treeview: how to select and set focus on a row?

Tags: python, ttk

I have a ttk.Treeview widget with some rows of data.  How do I set the focus to and select (highlight) a specified item?

```
tree.focus_set()
```

does nothing

```
tree.selection_set(0)
```

complains that: Item 0 not found, although the widget is plainly populated with more than zero items. Trying item 1 does no better.

EDIT: to select an item, find its id, then use tree.selection_set(id).  Neither tree.focus(id) nor tree.focus_set(id) appears to do anything.

Answer (score 14):

Get the id of treeview item you want to highlight/select

```
child_id = tree.get_children()[-1] # for instance the last element in tuple
```

To highlight the item, use both `focus()` and `selection_set(item_id)`

```
tree.focus(child_id)
tree.selection_set(child_id)
```

Comment: tree.selection_set(iid) works for me, focus does not. (Neither focus(iid) nor focus_set(iid)). I'm using Python 3.6.8. What I find surprising is that you can selection_set() before entering mainloop()

Comment: On python 3.10.6 I read the selected item using selected = tree.focus() before sorting a column, after I select the item again with tree.focus(selected) and tree.selection_set(selected) and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I haven't worked with python.

Looking at [this](http://docs.python.org/library/ttk.html#treeview) link, the `focus` method with optional parameter item, should highlight the node.

If not, look at `selectmode` option & set it to `"browse"`.

Comment: focus doesn't seem to work.  selection_set() wants an item id, not a position, which can be obtained when inserting or by iterating tree.get_children(). +1 for forcing me to re-read the docs. This get me highlight, but not focus.

Answer (score 3):

Come across this question when I'm looking to solve the exact same problem.

Found out this:

`tree.selection_set(item)` highlights the item

`tree.focus(item)` or `tree.focus_set(item)` selects the item

Comment: `tree.selection_set(item)` and `tree.focus(item)` worked for me.  I'm using Python 2.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
def mycallback(event):
    _iid = treeview.identify_row(event.y)
    global  last_focus
    if _iid != last_focus:
        if last_focus:
            treeview.item(last_focus, tags=[])
        treeview.item(_iid, tags=['focus'])
        last_focus = _iid

treeview.tag_configure('focus', background='red')
global last_focus
last_focus = None
treeview.bind("<Motion>", mycallback)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
    tree.selection_add(item_iid)

The reason why
    tree.selection_set(0) doesn't work is because 0 is not the item iid, it's the index you're referring to and Treeview is expecting an iid.